# "cast a shadow on someone's heart"

Tags: meaning

What does "someone or something casts a shadow on someone else's heart" mean?

For example, can I say a potentially deadly disease cast a shadow on my heart?

Thanks!

Comment: To me, when something casts a shadow on someone's heart, it means that something makes her feel sad, unhappy, and gloomy. This is mostly emotionally related. It's not about a deadly disease of any kinds.

Comment: [cast a shadow over/on sth](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/cast-a-shadow-over-on-sth)

Comment: @DamkerngT.: Does it make sense or is it good say that some disease cast a shadow on my heart?

Comment: @Tim It might, but I think it's unlikely for people to say a disease *casts a shadow on someone's heart*. In short, I agree with Susan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this metaphor takes on a different meaning depending on how a culture defines shadow (and on that, much is written.)

Since it's an English metaphor, we can interpret it from this culture.

Shadow is what is hidden from the light. In many ways, shadow has a negative connotation: something dangerous "lurks in the shadows"; someone guilty of some crime "lives in the shadows"; things are hidden in shadows. Melancholia, or "black bile" means sadness, gloom.

Light has a different connotation. "Bright as day", "bright as the sun, "Fair as the moon and joyful as the light", a "sunny disposition" is a happy one.

So, if light is joy/happy and dark is sad/gloomy, then to cast a shadow on something is to remove joy. Especially  when said of the heart, the Western seat of emotions, it is to make someone sad.

Since it is metaphorical, I would not say that a deadly disease cast a shadow on (my) heart. I would say it saddened me or that I was depressed.  But of intangible things, a metaphor does nicely: His rejection cast a shadow over her heart, or her love lifted the shadow over his heart.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've seen on here in quite some time. Too bad I can only upvote it once.